# Which Library Does <%#: Use?

Tags: .net, html-encode, antixsslibrary, .net-4.6.1

I have an asp.net 4.6.1 site and I need to use htmlencoding on some values. If I use the new (as of .NET 4.5) automatic html databinding encoding expression, <%#: to html encode my values, what library will it use? Server.htmlencode or System.Web.Security.AntiXss? Is there a way to get it to use System.Web.Security.AntiXss by default?